# Finding any text within numerical column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to find only text within column B?
Can the query function be used to find all characters within a column? e.g. df.query('colB == a-z')

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | abd |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | gth |
| 6 | 4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, if you want test whether the values in `Col B` contain strings from a to z, you can use `pd.str.contains` with a regex pattern, for example:

```
df['Col B'].str.contains(r'[a-z]')
```

And if you wish to filter with those particular rows:

```
df[df['Col B'].str.contains(r'[a-z]',na=False)]
```

Will return:

```
   Col A Col B
1      2   abd
4      5   gth
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. Written and tested in pandas version `'0.20.1'`.

```
import pandas as pd
df[df['ColB'].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')]
```

***Explanation:*** Using regular expression here to check if data frame's Column B contains alphabets throughout the values only alphabets then print that row of df. [df.str.contains documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: Careful with the output of `str.contains()`.

Comment: @CeliusStingher, Thank you for your comment, could you please explain more on it, because when I run this, it worked for me with shown/given samples, thank you.

Comment: That's strange, because `.str.contains` returns `NaN` for those values that doesn't match. Therefore I am getting `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values` when copy-pasting your code. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Thanks you Sir, it probably has to do with the versions then! In the newer versions, it returns `NaN` and you can use the parameter `na=False` to account for this. Happy learning to you too and Merry Xmas!

Comment: @CeliusStingher, Is it possible to loop over multiple columns to find strings in a numerical column?

Comment: Sure, but if there strings, then it won't be a numerical column. You can open a new question and put the link in the comments so I can take a look at it.