# Loop over multiple columns to find strings in a numerical column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The following code finds any strings for column B. Is it possible to loop over multiple columns of a dataframe outputting the cells containing strings for each column?

```
import pandas as pd
for i in df:
     print(df[df['i'].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')])
```

Link to code above
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65410078/12801962

Comment: What is your actual problem? Can you loop? Yes

Comment: This doesn't sound right: *find strings in a numerical column*.

Comment: You are wanting to apply str.contains to multiple columns, instead of just 'ColB'?

Comment: Based on this question and the linked one I think you have more problems than just finding strings.  If you describe your entire problem you will likely get more useful help.  There are ways to convert columns from str to numeric while handling errors etc.  Or checking the dtype of a column to find just the ones that are non-numeric.   Anyway consider re-wording what is really going on

Comment: if a column is numerical, as in `df.dtypes[colname] != np.dtype('O')`, then there are no strings in it. The condition you list doesn't check for that at all; it checks that, assuming that the column contains only strings (otherwise you'll get an `AttributeError`), it matches strings that contain one or more ASCII letters. So the question is: what are you really trying to do?

Comment: pls paste your other columns sample

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to loop through columns

```
import pandas as pd
colList = ['ColB', 'Some_other', 'ColC']
for col in colList:
    subdf = df[df[col].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')]
    #do something with sub DF
```

or do it in one long test and get all the problem rows in one dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
subdf = df[((df['ColB'].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')) |
            (df['Some_other'].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')) |
            (df['ColC'].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you are intending to do

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ColA'] = ['ABC', 'DEF', 12345, 23456]
df['ColB'] = ['abc', 12345, 'def', 23456]

all_trues = pd.Series(np.ones(df.shape[0], dtype=np.bool))
for col in df:
  all_trues &= df[col].str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')

df[all_trues]
```

Which will give the result:

```
    ColA    ColB
0   ABC     abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for k, s in df.astype(str).items():
    print(s.loc[s.str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')])
```

Or, for the values only (no index nor column information):

```
for k, s in df.astype(str).items():
    print(s.loc[s.str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')].values)
```

Note, both of the above only work because you just want to print the matching values in the columns, not return a new structure with filtered entries.

If you tried to make a new DataFrame with cells filtered by the condition, then that would lead to ragged arrays, which are not implemented (you could replace these cells by a marker of your choice, but you cannot cut them away).  Another possibility would be to select rows where `any` or `all` the cells present the condition you are testing for (that way, the result is an homogeneous array, not a ragged one).

Yet another option would be to return a list of `Series`, each representing a column, or a `dict` of `colname: Series`:

```py
{k: s.loc[s.str.contains(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')] for k, s in df.astype(str).items()}
```